# How are dunder methods accessed?

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators

```
number = 5

print(number.__class__)
print(number.__str__())
print(number.__add__(1))

#Output

<class 'int'>
5
6
```

I guess I'm trying to see if I understand this correctly.

So there's different ways to access the dunder methods. In the first case, it looks as though I'm accessing the method as though it were an attribute of the class `int`. In this case, is `__class__` using an `@property` decorator to access it as though it were an attribute? If that's the case, then it makes sense.

Second and third make sense. `__str___` is a dunder method defined in the class `int` that takes no arguments. You call it like a method. `__add__` takes a argument, which is the number you're adding to it. So you have to call it like a method with an argument. So none of these use `@property` decorators.

I guess what makes it more confusing is that technically the `__str__` can be made into an attribute with the `@property` decorator. I tested it out myself on my own class and it definitely works either way, so it seems a bit arbitrary which ones are accessed like attributes and which ones are accessed like methods. Assuming my theory is correct.

Comment: `__class__` is [an attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes), not a method.

Answer (score 2):

> So there's different ways to access the dunder methods. In the first case, it looks as though I'm accessing the method as though it were an attribute of the class `int`.

That's because `__class__` is an attribute, not a method.

Another distinction to make is that the way you access methods is always the same. Dunder methods are not magical in this. You use a `.` between the instance and the method name. Whether you are referring just to the method or calling it to get its result is another matter.

While this is a reasonable exercise to understand how Python works, remember that you should not usually call dunder methods directly. Python offers other syntax that will call these methods under the hood. For example, use `str(number)` instead of `number.__str__()` and `a + b` rather than `a.__add__(b)`.

The main reason for dunder methods is that they allow you to override default behavior in your own classes. They aren't intended to be called directly.

Comment: How about read-only methods which don't actually have a built-in function? Like `__members__` in Enum classes?

Comment: @ErikvandeVen What about them?

Comment: you mention that the main reason for dunder methods is that they allow you to override default behavior and aren't intended to be called directly. But what's now mentioned over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857519/dunder-methods-for-overloading is that not all of them have a built-in function to call them. In that case you have to call them directly else there is no way of using them

Comment: @ErikvandeVen `__members__` is a field, not a method. Perhaps, I'm being a bit pedantic here, but this is the source of my confusion from your first comment. I don't understand what this has to do with dunder methods since your example isn't a method.

Comment: I guess I try to understand this as well. So ok, these are attributes (or members), but still: they both use double underscores but the methods have syntax which calls them under the hood (like `str()`)... Why would we handle attributes differently? Or is there a best practice for using them? It feels ugly to actually use the dunder attributes right inside the code. If it doesn't make sense what I'm saying, shoot! Maybe I'm not thinking straight, but I can't get this quite straight in my head.