# Dunder methods for overloading

Tags: python

For dunder methods like `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` we have a function which access this special methods like `getattr()`, so we only have to use these dunder methods for overloading (i.e. add/change behavior of this special method in your class).

For `__members__` in `Enum` classes this is unclear. Which function to use to access the values which this dunder method returns, without explicitly accessing this dunder method? Is there one?

Or is it actually OK to use this dunder method directly? It doesn't feel right, though.

Is there any clear reference anywhere which built-in functions use which dunder methods? Because I'm not able to find them in their docs that quickly.

Comment: Dunder names are *generally* reserved for Python-internal use, meaning you should not create your own dunders or they _may_ clash with something somewhere. `__members__` is a specific implementation detail of `Enum`. Just because it's a dunder doesn't mean there's some builtin function or operator that uses it. It just means it's reserved by Python.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for your quick response. I wasn't planning to create my own dunder methods though. I was mainly keeping in mind that you want to *overload* dunder methods and not necessarily using them directly in your code. So like `getattr(MyClass)` vs `MyClass.__getattr__`.  But as I understand, this might be different depending on the dunder methods? I only read from the documentation that `__members__` is a read-only mapping.

Comment: Well I have seen many implementations that uses ``__members__`` as well as other dunder methods directly and there's nothing wrong with it. Though, generally you would prefer to use a function to access those if there is one.

Comment: so, just as an example, look at the difference between: `1 + 1.0` and `(1).__add__(1.0)`

Comment: My point was that your generic expectation of 1 dunder == 1 function is wrong. So, if you want to know what `Enum.__members__` does specifically and how to use it, you should make your question specifically about that.

Comment: Thank you all, for all your input! I'll definitely have another look at the datamodel. Start reading it now. Guess we never stop learning

Answer (score 2):

Technically [`__members__` is a "supported dunder name"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-dunder-names) so it's probably valid to invoke it directly, but I'd question why and whether you need this access in the first place:

- if you need to map values to enum instances, you can just index the enum:

  ```
  >>> Foo['A']
  <Foo.A: 1>
  ```
- if want to iterate all the values of the enum, you can do that directly:

  ```
  >>> list(Foo)
  [<Foo.A: 1>, <Foo.B: 2>]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Many dunder methods are *hooks* used by the various built-in functions or by operators. They do not correspond directly, though.

For example, `getattr(x, attr)` is **not the same** as `x.__getattr__(attr)`.

Same as the fact that `x + y` is **not the same** as `x.__add__(y)`.

```
>>> 1 + 1.0
2.0
>>> (1).__add__(1.0)
NotImplemented
>>>
```

Or, for the case of `__getattr__` and `getattr`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.x = 42
...    def __getattr__(self, attr):
...       return 0
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> getattr(foo, "x")
42
>>> foo.__getattr__("x")
0
```

So it is important to understand that these methods are used in a particular way by Python, but they aren't precisely equivalent.

And not all dunders are hooks, e.g. `__name__`. Anyway, here is the relevant documentation if you want to understand how most dunder names are used by the language https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Perhaps some are found in the documentation for the specific module, as is the case for `__members__`.